# Rails get random record where field has specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get a random record where the value of a field `status` is `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about speed this might be faster:

```
Model.where(status: 2).offset(rand(Model.where(status: 2).count)).first
```

Comment: `OFFSET` in MySQL is notoriously slow as well and sometimes `COUNT(*)` can take ages.

Answer (score 1):

The really hack way to do this is:

```
Model.where(:status => 2).order('RAND()').first
```

Note that `ORDER BY RAND()` can be brutally slow on large tables, but for small ones it's fine.